# MySQL / PHP: Use inner join if value isn't 0

Tags: php, mysql, join

I want to use a select query which gets data from tables.

It looks like this

```
SELECT table1.value1, table1.value2, table1.id, table2.id, table2.value2
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table2.id = table1.value4
ORDER BY table1.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Though `table1.value4` can sometimes be 0 and there are no `table2.id` with the value 0 and since it's a auto-increment value, it starts at 1. And I want it to start at 1.

Because when it's equal to 0 then that specific row isn't available, just the other ones.

But I would like to some how set a where clause that it only should get the `table2` values if `table1.value4` isn't equal to 0.

Comment: where table1.value4 <> 0   -- actually if all table2.id is non-zero , your inner join will not pick up any zero table1.value4 rows even without the where clause

Comment: As @dan_l said - unless you mean you want the table1 values to appear even though there are no corresponding table2 values. In which case you should consider LEFT JOIN instead of INNER.

Comment: Did you try with some test data? I think dan_I is correct. Your join should take care of that already

Comment: Yeah well that's the problem. I want it to pick up all the table1 values even if table1.value4 is 0

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't explained very well. Though changing INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you actually want, it seems, is a `LEFT JOIN` then.  All rows from `table1` will be returned, even if there is no match in `table2` (as with `table1.value4 = 0`).

```
SELECT table1.value1, table1.value2, table1.id, table2.id, table2.value2
FROM
  table1
  LEFT JOIN table2
    ON table2.id = table1.value4
ORDER BY table1.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

TRy this::

If you dont have 0 in table2 id, the below query works fine::

```
SELECT table1.value1, table1.value2, table1.id, table2.id, table2.value2
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table2.id = table1.value4
ORDER BY table1.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

But there are some values in table2 having id 0 and you want that to be ignored then

```
SELECT table1.value1, table1.value2, table1.id, table2.id, table2.value2
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON (table2.id = table1.value4 and table1.id!=0)
ORDER BY table1.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```